Input dependiente php mysql
El siguiente código no devuelve el valor para el input "Unidad" al seleccionar el select "tipo".
La conexión al servidor esta bien por que el select me muestra datos del la bd, pero la $unidadSeleccionada no muestra valores ni tampoco el mensaje de "error" que debe mostrar si no se ha seleccionado algún dato.
Estoy trabajando dentro de una página en Wordpress. Me funciona todo el resto de código, menos esta dependencia que quiero hacer.
<?php
include '../db.php';

// Crear un array de tipos y unidades
$tipos = array();

// Consulta SQL para obtener los tipos y sus unidades
$sql = "SELECT T_Nombre, T_Unidad FROM TIPOS WHERE T_Estado = 'activo'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Verificar si la consulta devuelve resultados
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Recorrer los resultados y construir el array $tipos
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tipos[$row['T_Nombre']] = $row['T_Unidad'];
    }
}

// Procesar el formulario cuando se envía
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $tipoSeleccionado = $_POST["Tipo"];
    $unidadSeleccionada = $tipos[$tipoSeleccionado] ?? ""; // Obtener la unidad correspondiente al tipo seleccionado
} else {
    $unidadSeleccionada = "Error"; // Por defecto, cuando no se ha seleccionado ningún tipo
}
?>

<tr>
    <th>Tipo</th>
    <th>Unidad</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Stock</th>
    <th>Ingresar</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST" id="bodegaForm">
        <td>
            <select name="Tipo" id="tipoSelect">
            <option value=""></option>
                <?php foreach ($tipos as $tipo => $unidad) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $tipo . '">' . $tipo . '</option>';
                } ?>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Unidad" value="<?php echo $unidadSeleccionada ; ?>" readonly>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Nombre" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="number" name="Stock" value=""></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Ingresar"></td>
    </form>
</tr>

<?php
$conn->close();
?>

¿Hay algún error?

si tienes un selec que no se ve como se comunica con el php no basta con tener un select eso por si solo no hara nada...

Luis, como llevas esto? Para ver que es lo nuevo que has intentado, que errores tienes aun y valorar si poder recrear este escenario
